# How do you combine two objects in java

Tags: java

I have 2 objects that I need to combine before passing it to another method.

```
Status status1 = null;
Status status2 = null;  
Status statusCombined = null;   

status1 =  validationService.validateDocument(documentA);
status2 =  validationService.validateDocument(documentB);

if (!status1.equals(status2) {
//merge status1 and status 2 to  statusCombined
  setValidationStatus(validationResults,statusCombined);
```

What is the command to combined these 2 objects with same properties?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "combine?"

Comment: also don't use `==` to compare, use `equals`.

Comment: I want to create another object statusCombined containing status1 and status2.  Thanks.

Comment: easy just create a class with two attributes each one of status object type

Comment: What does `Status` class contains ?

Comment: if(status1.equals(status2document) {

Comment: just curious to know if have you seen this "combine objects" operation in another language that you want to know the counterpart in java.

Comment: So, if status1 and status2 are same then you want to combine them? That's not making any sense. You need to explain the context better.

Comment: It only contains statuscodes, an integer value.

Comment: Sorry if not equal, I want to combine it.

Comment: If they have the same property, return 1 of them... Or do you have any other idea of "combination"

Comment: Put all the status codes in statusCombined object.

Comment: I need to pass the combined status to another method like this:
if (!status1.equal(status2) {
   setValidationStatus(validationResults, combinedStatus);

Comment: You should edit your original question rather than posting code as a comment (where it's impossible to read).  While you're at it, you should add **A LOT OF INFORMATION** about what you're trying to do.  Right now you're expecting us to read your mind.  You need to provide a specific description of what you mean when you say "_combine statuses_".  We would like to help, but you're making it almost impossible.  Imagine what it would be like to try to answer this question if you knew **NOTHING** about what the person is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the command to combined these 2 objects with same properties?

In the general sense, there is no "command" (or method) in Java that can combine "properties" of two objects into one, because:

- It doesn't make sense to talk about "combining" two things without saying what "combine" means.
- Even if it did make sense in particular cases, being able to do it in general cases doesn't make sense.
- Even if it did make sense in general, it would violate the object's encapsulation to do it.

---

If you have a particular case where it does make sense, then you need to add a method or constructor to your `Status` class that produces a combined status from two existing status ... using whatever algorithm you decide is semantically appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You've made it pretty hard to figure out what you mean (by providing zero details).

But... Here is how you could create a class that contains two *Status* objects.

```
class CombinedStatus {

    private Status statusOne;
    private Status statusTwo;

    public CombinedStatus(Status s1, Status s2) {
        statusOne = s1;
        statusTwo = s2;
    }

    public Status getStatusOne() {
        return statusOne;
    }

    public Status getStatusTwo() {
        return statusTwo;
    }
}
```

How to use it:

```
CombinedStatus cs = new CombinedStatus(status1, status2);
```

For us to provide a better answer, you will have to provide some detail as to what you're after.

For example: What on earth does it mean to combine two statuses?

Do you add them together?  Multiply them?  Peform some logical operations?

We have no clue if you don't tell us.

Comment: What about this `Status statusCombined`?

Comment: I have no idea... I'm just trying to read the OP's mind (since he's provided exactly zero useful pieces of information)!

Comment: `class CombinedStatus extends Status { /* ... */ }` ?

Comment: Who knows... we're all just stabbing in the dark trying to guess what the OP wants.

Comment: Sorry, I just started coding Java and first time posting to this board.

Comment: Just try to describe what you want.  Be specific and remember that we have no idea what you mean unless you tell us. Your question is going to get closed soon because it is currently impossible to understand what you mean.  You keep saying you want to combine the statuses, but you never once define what it means to combine two statuses.